# Can't use offscreencanvas with react-three-fiber

Tags: web-worker, react-three-fiber, offscreen-canvas

I am using offscreencanvas (https://threejs.org/manual/#en/offscreencanvas) to render react-three-fiber elements on a separate thread. There are not a lot of resources about this on the internet (however I found this issue: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/280). I tried reproducing it but I get an error.

Main thread create canvas:

```
// main.jsx (main thread)

    import React from "react";

    export const Main = () => {
      const canvasRef = React.useRef();

      React.useEffect(() => {
        const offscreen = canvasRef.current.transferControlToOffscreen();

        const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

        worker.postMessage({
          canvas: offscreen,
        }, [offscreen])
      }, []);

      return (
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
      );
    }
```

Separate thread:

```
// worker.jsx (worker thread)
import { render } from 'react-three-fiber';
import { WebGLRenderer, Scene, PerspectiveCamera } from 'three';

self.onmessage = (event) => {
  const { canvas } = event.data;

  const scene = new Scene();
  const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
  const camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 75, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 1000 );

  render(<gridHelper scale={[10, 10, 10]}/>, scene);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

When I render this, I get an error saying "Cannot read property of undefined". Could anyone help me identify why I get this error? Or provide a demo using offscreencanvas with react-three-fiber?

Comment: What is `ctx` in worker.jsx? Which line does this error come from?

Comment: it should be `self` instead of `ctx`. The error comes from the render method, in worker.jsx `render(<gridHelper scale={[10, 10, 10]}/>, scene)`, from react-three-fiber. Looks like, react three fiber needs to use DOM elements, however in the secondary thread it can only access the canvas passed. I'd like to see a demo using offscreen-canvas with react three fiber (if it is possible). But I just can't find enough info about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://f-loat.github.io/offscreen-canvas-demo

GitHub: https://github.com/F-loat/offscreen-canvas-demo

```js
// main.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const offscreen = canvasRef.current.transferControlToOffscreen();

    const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));

    worker.postMessage( {
      drawingSurface: offscreen,
      width: canvas.clientWidth,
      height: canvas.clientHeight,
      pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
    }, [ offscreen ] );
  }, []);

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
  );
}

export default App
```

```js
// worker.js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { extend, useFrame, createRoot, events } from '@react-three/fiber'

extend(THREE)

function Cube(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef()
  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false)
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  // Subscribe this component to the render-loop, rotate the mesh every frame
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    mesh.current.rotation.x += 0.01
    mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01
  })
  // Return view, these are regular three.js elements expressed in JSX
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={active ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={() => setHover(true)}
      onPointerOut={() => setHover(false)}>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ambientLight />
      <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
      <Cube position={[0, 0, 0]} />
    </>
  );
}

self.onmessage = (event) => {
  const { drawingSurface: canvas, width, height, pixelRatio } = event.data;

  const root = createRoot(canvas)

  root.configure({
    events,
    size: {
      width,
      height,
    },
    dpr: pixelRatio, // important
  })

  root.render(<App />)
}
```

```
// @react-three/fiber/dist/index-1e2a4313.esm.js

+ var window = self || window

- gl.setSize(size.width, size.height);
+ gl.setSize(size.width, size.height, false);
```